# How to use 2 actions in 1 action support?

Tags: visualforce

suppose, I want to get the value of a picklist onload and onchange, can i set 2 events in the apex:action support? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can have as many actionSupport elements on a single element as you like, but each can only be bound to one event. However, if more than one event handler triggers at once, only the last defined one will take effect.

For example, this doesn't work as you might expect:

```
<apex:page controller="DualAction">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:inputText value="{!text}">
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!action1}" event="onblur" reRender="form"/>
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!action2}" event="onchange" reRender="form"/>
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If you have code like this, then clicking into and out of the field (blurring it), you'll call action1, but if you change the contents of the field and *then* move out of it, it will call action2 *instead* of action1. In other words, they do not both execute, but it will have a different behavior based on which events fire and the order of the declared functions.